# Content miss match

Tags: python, binary

I am using python script to copy data of a file into other

```
input_file = open('blind_willie.MP3', 'rb')
contents = input_file.read()
output_file = open('f2.txt', 'wb')
output_file.write(contents)
```

When I open f2 using text editor I see these kind of symbols:

```
ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿù`‘~ +Pg]Nñòs
```

Is there a way to see the binary content of the f2 file?

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to see?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You have described your program, and what the output is. Can you also describe what output you *expect* to see?

Comment: You read binary content and wrote it to another file, effectively making a copy. What did you *expect* to see instead?

Comment: Do you want the lyrics? ;)

Comment: @Santosh Kumar...  If you will go through the few lines of code... you will get to know that the file has been opened up in binary mode and the data in new file is also being written in binary format... Hope you understand...

Comment: @Robᵩ... i am expecting to see binary or hexadecimal output...(in human readable form)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to see the binary content of the `f2` file, and you have discovered it. Those symbols represent the binary content of the file.

If you'd like to see a human-readable interpretation of the binary content, you'll need something like a hex dump program or hex editor.

On Linux, I use the `hd` or `od -t x1` command.

If you'd like to write your own hex dump command, you might start with one of these:

- [scapy hexdump()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10998079/scapy-hexdump)
- `contents.encode("hex")`
- http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577243-hex-dump/
- http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576945/

Or you could use this code:

```
def hd(data):
    """ str --> hex dump """
    def printable(c):
        import string
        return c in string.printable and not c.isspace()
    result = ""
    for i in range(0, len(data), 16):
        line = data[i:i+16]
        result += '{0:05x} '.format(i)
        result += ' '.join(c.encode("hex") for c in line)
        result += " " * (50-len(line)*3)
        result += ''.join(c if printable(c) else '.' for c in line)
        result += "\n"
    return result

input_file = open('blind_willie.MP3', 'rb')
contents = input_file.read()
output_file = open('f2.txt', 'wb')
output_file.write(hd(contents))
```

Comment: For hex reads (in Python) you can use `encode()` `f2_file = f2_file.encode("hex")` +1

Comment: @Robᵩ... the output file in hex format doesn't provide the replica of original file .... As i tried to play this file in audacity using raw data import and it just gives a horn kind of sound where as the original file is completely different...
Is there a possibility that the hex data would get changed ??

Comment: Right - the output file is **human**-readable. If you want an **Audacity**-readable file, use your original code.